# Android: draw route from A to B in GoogleMap API v2

Tags: android, dictionary, gps, routes

As we know, soon GoogleMap API v1 will be deprecated and we've seen some tutorials on how to draw route from A to B in MapView (lets say A is some building in Moscow and B is some building in Warsaw)

However, browsing the internet, I haven't found any decent tutorial on how to get and draw route on GoogleMap (not in MapView).

In tutorial that I've seen and used there was used KMLHandler, but parsing failed.

So does anyone know is it possible to draw route on GoogleMap from A to B?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

The Android developers website have the whole procedure very well explained:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/lines

Comment: I've seen that, but what I truly need is to draw on path in the map and also I need to get the shortest route

Comment: There're 2 different problems here that you're not acknowledging. 1 is how to draw the lines on the map; and that is answered on the tutorial. 2 is how to calculate a route between points, and that is a much more complex problem, and is the reason only huge companies with a lot of know-how like Google or Tom-Tom do it. So answering to your question: is it possible to draw a route? Yes it is! But how to find out the route is something else.

Comment: And Google doesn't give any functionality to ease finding the shortest route?